# A question about generic points.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $x$ be a point in $X$.
In Hartshorne's book, I saw the the following definition of a generic point:

> $x$ is a generic point of $X$ if $\{x\}$ is dense in $X$.

But, in Qing Liu's book, I saw another definition of a generic point:

> $x$ is a generic point of $X$ if $x$ is the unique point of $X$ that specialize to $x$
>   that is, for a point $y \in X$ if x is contained in the closure of $\{y\}$ then $x=y$.

I don't know why these definitions are equivalent....

Comment: I'm confused. If $X = \{0,1\}$ with a discrete topology, no points are dense in $X$. At the same time, $\{0\}$ satisfies the second definition - if $y\in \mathrm{Cl}\{0\} =\{0\}$ then $y = 0$.

Comment: The second definition is not quite correct: it should also say that every point is a specialisation of $x$.

Comment: Then, these are distinct???

Comment: Dear @Zhen, I don't think that Liu intended his definition to coincide with Hartshorne's except in the irreducible case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definitions are different. With Hartshorne's, only irreducible schemes have a (necessarily unique) generic point. With Liu's "generic point" means "Hartshorne generic point of an irreducible component." They coincide precisely for irreducible schemes.